# Built in webcam installation

Tags: webcam

I am following instructions to install a built in webcam. The instructions state I have to install [Cheese](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Cheese), but every time after entering the command and my password, an error appear: `unable to locate package cheese`.

This is what it shows every time:

```
wtc@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install cheese
[sudo] password for wtc: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cheese
wtc@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to install it.

Download it from here

if your computer is 32bit (has 2GB RAM or less) [click here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cheese/cheese_3.8.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb)

if it's 64bit [click here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cheese/cheese_3.8.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb)

open the file when you download it